# How to debug run time error 1004 due to "worksheet protection" when worksheet is not protected

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

TL;DR
making worksheet visible produces error due to worksheet protection, even though worksheet is NOT protected!

**The problem in prose**:
I've created a an application in excel that uses individual worksheets as user interfaces. At the top, I have a list of objects that serve as buttons to navigate the application. This works as expected most of the, but on occasion produces an error due to worksheet protection, this despite the worksheet not being protected.

**The code** that is called by the buttons:

```
Public Sub HideAllOtherSheets(targetSheet As Worksheet)
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook

'Ensure target sheet is visible
For Each wks In Wkb.Worksheets
    If wks.Name = targetSheet.Name Then
        wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
Next wks

'Now make all others invisible
For Each wks In Wkb.Worksheets
    If wks.Name <> targetSheet.Name Then
        wks.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
Next wks

Set Wkb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**The error:**
The runtime error 1004 occurs on the line `wks.Visible = xlSheetVisible` in the first `For ... Each`, but it does not occur consistently.

Strangest of all... if I then go to debug and simply press F5, it continues running without repeating the error message!

I was experimenting with using `.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True` but have taken that code out again. Since experimenting with that I have had this problem.

**What I have tried:**

1. I inserted a direct `.Unprotect` statement in the line prior to the one making the worksheet visible, but the error still occurs. To the best of my knowledge it shouldn't even matter that the worksheet is locked.
2. Inserted code that unlocks all worksheets when the workbook is opened. Error still occurs.

Comment: Have you tried changing the attribute `xlSheetVeryHiddem` to `xlSheetHidden`, I know that users would then be able to change the visibility of the worksheet but this might help.

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but I can not use that option, because as you mentioned, then users can unhide the other sheets and that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.